# php and ffmpeg 500 internal server error

Tags: php, ffmpeg

i'm trying to extract a single frame from a video file using the following php code:

```
$cmd = 'ffmpeg -i "d:\webs\beta\test\sample2.mp4" -vframes 1 -s 146x82 -f image2 "d:\webs\beta\test.jpg"';
exec($cmd, $rc);
```

the problem is that i'm getting an 500 internal server error the first time i'm trying to execute the script, but when reloading it works.
so it means when reloading: works / doesn't work / works ..

any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Does the cmd work outside of PHP?

Comment: yes works nicely. also works with php but as i said only each 2nd time

Comment: What does the error log say? And it works every time from cmd line?

Comment: be sure that the output folder is writable or this will process will fail

Answer (score 1):

Try this script.

```
<?php

$ffmpeg = "/full/path/to/ffmpeg";

$videoFile = "/full/path/to/video.mp4";

$imgOut = "/full/path/to/frame.jpg";

$second = 0;

$cmd = $ffmpeg." -i \"".$videoFile."\" -an -ss ".$second.".001 -y -f mjpeg \"".$imgOut."\" 2>&1";

$feedback = `$cmd`;


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem exactly.

using proc_open instead of exec and its variants fixed it.

Roey